# How to overide HardwareButtons_BackPressed of Basic Page in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have two pages in my app.One is blankPage and other is basic page. On basic page I want to provide a message if a user press back button like 
"Are you sure you want to quit" .If Yes then go back else remain there , this working fine by using this code

```
 HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
private async void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to quit you will loose all your work ?", "Warning");
            dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", new UICommandInvokedHandler(CommandHandler1)));
            dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", new UICommandInvokedHandler(CommandHandler1)));




            await dlg.ShowAsync();
    }



 private void CommandHandler1(IUICommand command)
        {
            var label = command.Label;
            switch (label)
            {
                case "Yes":
                    {
                        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                        break;
                    }
                case "No":
                    {
                        break;
                    }

            }

        }
```

But when I am pressing back button on my BlankPage this message also appears there and also appearing in all other basic page if I add more . What mistake am I doing??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are registering hardware back button in page constructor or page load event and once this event is registered you are not unregistering this event. BackPress is app level. for correctly using this event on your desired page register Back Press event in your OnNavigatedTo override method and unregister this event in OnNavigatedFrom ovrride metho. here is how.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }
```